# Concurrent transactions in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I have the same module that connect with database running in two servers (back and front). Its connect with the same database.

I use JPA (Hibernate implementation) and Spring transaction management.

I have the following problem:

I have to update the fieldA from tableA with the MAX value + 1 of two different fields (fieldA from tableA, fieldB from tableB)

**Case1:**

Before update

**tableA**
*fA* = 100

**tableB**
*fB* = 102

After update

**tableA**
*fA* = 103

**tableB**
*fB* = 102

---

**Case2:**

Before update

**tableA**
*fA* = 102

**tableB**
*fB* = 100

After update

**tableA**
*fA* = 103

**tableB**
*fB* = 100

The method with this code is transactional and do things before (like create the entity) and after that. So before commit the transaction if the other application try to get the value, it will be outdated and it will save the same value in fieldA. Hibernate sessions are different because the distributed system.

I can't use sequences in database (legal issues because it is about invoicing) or distributed cache for Hibernate (system issues)

How i can do that??

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use locking for that. The appropriate type of locking depends on your use case.

If the probability of a concurrent update is low, use optimistic locking. In case of an update collision, catch the `Exception`, refresh the entity, reapply your changes and retry the commit.

If you use optimistic locking, it is advised to add a `@Version` field to your entity. Optimistic locking without a version field is not guaranteed to be supported.

If the probability of a concurrent modification is high, use pessimistic locking. Thus you can serialize writes on the row. Note that this type of locking can create a bottleneck as transactions queue for updates and other transactions time out before acquiring the lock.

In order to minimize the lokc time, you can apply the lock on an individual query:

```
query.setLockMode(LockMode.WRITE)
```

EDIT: The locks can be probably used in a distributed environment safely.

Optimistic locking is implemented as a check on the `@Version` field in the DB at commit time (or equivalent) - with read-commited isolation (the default) there is no risk of missing a committed change to the entity.

Pessimistic locking is implemented on DB level, often using `SELECT FOR UPDATE` or similar. So you don't have to worry.

Comment: Thanks @kostja, are hibernate locks cluster-safe?(I have two servers sharing the same database)

Comment: You're welcome :) Yes, the locks are both cluster-safe: Please see the edit.

Comment: Wheter it's more or less likely to run into a race condition is the wrong question. The right question is: Wow your code (or user!) is able to resolve the conflict. If you can emmit an error message telling the user to try again, use optimistic locking. Doing the same thing purely programmatically and reliable is very hard. Catching the exception is just the entry point of a complex algorythm. That's why I think that pesimistic locking is the only easy way to solve this problem.

Comment: Yes, handling optimistic locking exceptions correctly can be a complex issue, but only if you choose to. Unhandled optimistic lock collisions have the same effect as unhandled pessimistic locking collisions - a transaction rollback. (it's a bit different for pessimistic timeout exceptions as they don't have to cause a complete TX rollback). The important difference here is that you **can** handle an optimistic lock error if you choose to. So I fail to see a gain in simplicity with pessimistic locking. However pessimistic locking has it's downsides.

Answer (score 1):

You need pesimistic locking. With Hibernate you can do this on the JDBC or transaction level.

Read the [chapter about locking](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html) in the hibernate manual.

Comment: You don't really **need** pessimistic locking here. Please consider providing the relevant information behind the link in addition to posting it.

Comment: It is highly unlikely (one or two cases per month, of 10.000)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly your question but maybe in your DAO you can prepare a method where you can do something this

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ClassA);
dc.setProjection(Projections.max("id"));
logger.info(svc.getMax(dc));
```

Once you got the max value you can update the other table

Angelo